# Update collection of entity given only ID and certain field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I would like to have a form where, given only the IDs of some entities and a field, all entities can be updated.

Something like this in input:

```
POST /entity/update
[ 
  [ 
    'id' => 30,
    'status' => 'ok'
  ],
  [
    'id' => 31,
    'status' => 'error'
  ]
]
```

Given only the ID, I managed to do a DataTransformer, but I can't find how to merge the new status in the entities.

How to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: This question isn't clear at all, please, try to be more accurate and explain better what you're trying to reach here. Thanks.